# Resolve git merge conflict by applying diff hunk to different file

Tags: vc, smerge

I have refactored a file by splitting into two files in one git branch, and someone else has made a different change to the original file on another git branch. This has produced a merge conflict in git when I tried to merge the second git branch into the first (which I did using magit). I have configured git to produce a 3-way diff surrounded by conflict markers in the file, and I have used `C-c ^ = >` to diff the original contents of the file and the second branch changes, which produces a `vc-diff` buffer.

How can I apply this `vc-diff` buffer to the *second* file, not the first file - either one hunk at a time, or all at once? I don't mind which way it is done, but I would prefer to do it one hunk at a time. (Bearing in mind that the line numbers will probably be different, but the surrounding text will be largely the same.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `C-c c-e` in the `vc-diff` buffer to apply the diff to a file. Enter the target filename and press `RET`. This will launch `ediff` and attempt to apply the patch.

For me, the patch applied successfully without any hitches, so I just needed to press `n` a few times in the ediff frame to review the result, and then `q` to quit the ediff session.

Then return to the buffer for the first file and resolve the original conflict (in my case, by simply accepting my changes, as I had applied the changes from the other branch to the other file).

Comment: If this resolves your problem, please accept your own answer so we can mark the post as done.